# Install DNode on Windows

Tags: windows-7-x64, dnode

I am trying to install DNode on Windows 7 64bit, Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express and Python 2.7.3 are installed.
I get the following output from npm:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install dnode
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/dnode
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/dnode
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jsonify
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/weak
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/dnode-protocol
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jsonify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/weak
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/dnode-protocol
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/traverse
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/traverse

> weak@0.2.1 install C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\dnode\node_modules\weak
> node-gyp rebuild

C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\dnode\node_modules\weak>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.InvalidPlatform.Targets(23,7): error MSB8007: The Platform for project 'weakref.vcxproj' is invalid.  Platform='x64'. You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\dnode\node_modules\weak\build\weakref.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:236:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:99:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process._handle.onexit (child_process.js:678:10)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\dnode\node_modules\weak
gyp ERR! node -v v0.8.14
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.7.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! weak@0.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the weak@0.2.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the weak package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls weak
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "dnode"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.14
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.65
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

C:\Program Files\nodejs>python -- version
Python 2.7.3
```

Command Prompt runs as Administrator.

"The Platform for project 'weakref.vcxproj' is invalid."?
is this a 32bit / 64bit issue?

It seems to be a problem with the C++ compilers.
So I installed the full 64bit version of .NET

and am now trying to install the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 (ISO) from DVD:
x64 ISO File GRMSDKX_EN_DVD.iso from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442

but the installation fails, with the following error: Please refer to Samples\Setup\HTML\ConfigDetails.htm document for further information.

Then I tried again after setting the Registry and verifying the TEM variable according to the suggestions here: http://ctrlf5.net/?p=184

Again, the SDK will not install

Any ideas what went wrong here and how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer on a forum which points out the [node-gyp installation instructions](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#installation). So Windows Visual C++ 2010 is required (Express edition is ok)
And [Windows 7 64-bit SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) is required too.

Pay attention to this troubleshooting tip:
*"If the install fails, try uninstalling any C++ 2010 x64&x86 Redistributable that you have installed first."*

I actually ran through this issue and fixed it by uninstalling my Visual C++ 2010 x64&x86 Redistributables and then installing Windows 7 64-bit SDK. Then I was able to build node-gyp and so forth to execute "npm install dnode" successfully.